# Dialogflow: Determine product name or Select a product from a list which are fetched using a webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a bot(custom UI in my website) where a user will enter a product name to view the details of it and I will provide a link to the product full details page. I have a situation where if the user enters a name and there are multiple results from my database, I want to show him those products as quick replies so that he can select one from them.

How do I recognize that the user has entered the product name and anything else? I can use @sys.any, but all small conversation will also go there, which will be of no use.

The same problem occurs when I display him a list of products with matching name. But now when the user clicks on any of the button I am taking him to a custom follow-up intent where I have entered the template for a product entity. But, dialogflow only recognizes the products that have been defined in the entity(listed few products and checked auto expand).

I have tried using @sys.any instead, but the intent is called for any string the user types in. Lets say, the user does not respond and after a while he types in "hi", my intent with any is being called. How do I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 2):

So far as I understand, I can see two ways to solve this query. First, using an entity & defining your product list over there for bot to understand user responses (which you have done) but this will become an overhead when you have a list of say 1000/more products. Second way, you can continue using `@sys.any` & define a parameter, write a webhook where you validate user entered response to product list in database & check if it is present over there, if yes, show product details or say, entered response is incorrect.